# Is there an auto increasing ID in the Nebula Graph?

Tags: nebula-graph

```
nebula> CREATE TAG IF NOT EXISTS t2 (name string, age int);                
nebula> INSERT VERTEX t2 (name, age) VALUES "11":("n1", 12);
nebula> INSERT VERTEX t2 (name, age) VALUES "13":("n3", 12), "14":("n4", 8);
```

Is there any way here for me to not create the vid values manually?

Answer (score 0):

The VID must be generated manually by users because NebulaGraph does not provide auto-increasing ID or UUID.